# ATX Standard for Wake-On-LAN

Tags: power-supply, power, wake-on-lan

I've read about the implementation of the "Wake-on-LAN" feature on Wikipedia. The article claims that at least an ATX 2.01 standard-compliant PSU is necessary. Quite alot of other resources on the internet support this statement.

I was somewhat curious about what [the standard](http://joule.bu.edu/~hazen/LinuxCluster/atx_201.pdf) defines and came across the following section:

> 5VSB is a standby voltage that may be used to power circuits that require power input during the powered-down state
>   of the power rails. **The 5VSB pin should deliver 5V ñ 5% at a minimum of 10mA** for PC board circuits to operate.
>   Conversely, PC boards should draw no more than 10mA maximum from this pin unless a power supply with higher
>   current capabilities is clearly specified. This power may be used to operate circuits such as soft power control. **For
>   future implementation, it is recommended that the 5VSB line be capable of delivering 720mA. This increased
>   current will be needed for future implementations with features such as “wake on LAN.”**

As far as I understand this section, the standard does not enforce 720mA but rather recommends it. Which in conclusion means that a PSU following the ATX 2.01 in a strict manner doesn't provide enough to support Wake-On-LAN.

Later standards like [ATX 2.1](http://www.formfactors.org/developer%5Cspecs%5Catx2_1.pdf) mention a recommendation of 2A in order to allow the Wake-On-LAN feature, but don't enforce such currents, too.

> 5VSB is a standby voltage that may be used to power circuits that require power input during the powered-
>   down state of the power rails. This power may be used to operate circuits such as soft power control. **It is
>   recommended that the 5VSB line be capable of delivering 2 A.** This current allows the implementation of
>   features such as Wake on LAN technology in accordance with IAPC (see
>   developer.intel.com/technology/iapc/index.htm for more information).

The ATX 2.3 specification is the first to actually enforce such currents (I cannot post more links as this is my first question on this stackexchange board):

> **The +5 VSB output should be capable of delivering a minimum of 2.0 A** at +5 V ± 5% to external 
>   circuits. The power supply **must be able** to provide the required power during a "wake up" event. If 
>   an external USB device generates the event, there may be peak currents as high as 2.5 A lasting no 
>   more than 500 ms.

Of course I assume that actual PSU manufacturers don't take the standard too strict and will certainly implement the recommendations instead of the minimal requirements to fulfill the standard.
Yet I'm wondering myself how to read such standards in the future. Also, I haven't found information on how much power the mainboard and network adapter actually needs to be in an acceptable "sleep" state.

EDIT: To provide a more specific question: I'd like to know if the statement "In order to support Wake-On-LAN the power supply must meet ATX 2.01 specifications." (as stated on Wikipedia) is true or not and why.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What is the specific question you'd like answered?

Comment: I'd like to know if the statement "In order to support Wake-On-LAN the power supply must meet ATX 2.01 specifications." (as stated on Wikipedia) is true or not (and, of course, why).